# TFS 2005 history very slow for some branches

Tags: tfs, tfs-2005

When I view history for some branches, it takes over 20 minutes for it to come up.  However the root of this branch works fine, and not all branches have this problem.  The children to this branch is also very slow.

Running TFS 2005 SP1.

Running the command line tf history gives the same issues.

I've rebooted the server and it does have enough CPU and memory.  Any ideas on what is causing the slowness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS repository and services are based on SQL server. Without a proper maintenance plan, the SQL database gets fragmented and over time endures performance degradation.

Consider [Restoration-Based Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28VS.80%29.aspx) to start your TFS server on a fresh database while keeping the same repository.

Comment: We plan on upgrading to TFS2010 soon, and doing that in the process.

Comment: There were a lot of performance improvements comparing TFS2005 to TFS2010. I am sure the history is one of them. So it is not related to SQL only.

Comment: I think that's the only way to go from here! Thanks.